# why is iterator objects variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, iterable

Learning to make objects iterable in Javascript.

Object is:

```
var arrayLikeObject = {
    0: "hello",
    1: "there",
    2: "crappy coder",
    length: 3,
}
```

then I do this to make it iterable:

```
arrayLikeObject[Symbol.iterator] = function(){
    return {
        current: 0, // <---- but... it IS defined.
        next() {
            // let current = 0; // putting it here makes it work
            if(current < this.length) {
                let a = current;
                current++;
                return {done: false, value: this[a]};
            }
            else {
                return {done: true};
            }
        }
    };
};
```

then when I run it with:

```
console.log("after making it iterable: ==============");
for(let str of arrayLikeObject) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

I get "current is not defined" But as far as I can see, it is. I just can not understand. I thought functions could see variables outside their scope, but not the other way around, unless they get "overshadowed" if that's the correct terminology. I forgot.

Comment: `current` -> `this.current`. A *variable* and an *object property* are different in JS.

Comment: Gotcha. Kinda forgot one needs to use this in object methods when creating an object literal, to use objects properties in its methods :-o. Is there another venue for questions like this, where someone just needs help when getting mentally blocked (after googling, checking tutorials and stackoverflow answer, and still cant get "unstuck"). Like, a second pair of eyes? Guessing these kind of questions get downvoted prety quickly x)

Comment: Actually. Just noticed (because of a bunch of other printouts getting in the way. It still does not work, I get no error by using ```if(this.current < this.length)``` anymore, but I get no results from the for...of loop either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current` is not a variable, it is a property, so you would need to reference it as `this.current`.

However, you have another issue with `this`:

In `this.length` and `this[a]`, the `this` object is not `arrayLikeObject`, but the object that has the `next()` method.

You can also fix this, but I think it is simpler to go the other way, and make `next` an arrow function. That way `this.length` and `this[a]` will work as intended. Make `current` a normal variable within the closure:

```js
var arrayLikeObject = {
    0: "hello",
    1: "there",
    2: "crappy coder",
    length: 3,
}

arrayLikeObject[Symbol.iterator] = function(){
    let current = 0;
    return {
        next: () => {
            if(current < this.length) {
                return {done: false, value: this[current++]};
            }
            else {
                return {done: true};
            }
        }
    };
};

console.log("after making it iterable: ==============");
for(let str of arrayLikeObject) {
    console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Rewrote it by explicitly creating an object and then after populating it before returning it (object called iterator). Avoided arrow functions, hence had to keep track of "this" and share it explicitly. Didn't want to present yet another thing, arrow functions, that i'm not comfortable with. Your explanation totally helped though :). I accept your answer.